# Is T Tauri a compulsory stage for stellar evolution?

Tags: star

Do all stars go from Protostar stage to T Tauri and then to Main Sequence or is T-Tauri stage only for certain stars?  If only certain stars, is that those that are less than 3 solar masses which i see mentioned?  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T_Tauri_star)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, only certain stars that are less than about 3 solar masses were T Tauri stars. Here are some reference and quotes that I saw to answer this question. There are all review papers.

> Our planetary system was formed in early stages of the suns evolution. What the sun was like at that time can be learned by observing young solar-mass stars.

https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/B:ASYS.0000003267.35552.f7

> T Tauri stars are newly formed low-mass stars that have recently become visible in the optical range,

https://www.annualreviews.org/doi/abs/10.1146/annurev.aa.27.090189.002031

> This review presents the main aspects of the body of knowledge on T Tauri variable stars, which are presumed to be young, gravitationally contracting low-mass stars.

http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0034-4885/47/2/001

Comment: Thanks for clarifying what I thought.  I presume the larger ones then skip T-Tauri and go straight to Main Sequence.